# How to obtain the values of a select element with multiple attribute using jinput?

Tags: joomla

I'm trying to get the values ​​of a select element that has the multiple attribute using jInput. I estimate to obtain a series of values ​​but only obtain the value of the last selected option

The definition of the select is as follows

```
... other inputs ...
<select name="jform[something]" id="something" multiple>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="...">...</option>
    <option value="Z">Z</option>
</select>
```

In the controller I have the following logic that obtains the values ​​of the inputs including the select.

```
$requestData = $this->input->post->get('jform', array(), 'array');
```

Here I hope that the value of the select is a series of selected values ​​but as I mentioned before I get only the value of the last selected option.

The content of `$requestData` looks like this

```
$requestData = [
    'name' => 'name',
    'lastname' => 'lastname',
    ...
    'something' => 'A' // Here I am expeting to have something like 'A,Z'
];
```

How do I get the desired values?

The controller code belongs to the controller `.../components/com_users/ controllers/registration.php` in the `register` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get multiple values from select box make that field as array.

Your field name will be - **jform[something][]**

```
<select name="jform[something][]" id="something" multiple>
   ...
</select>
```